# User upload dashboard

Tags: plugins, customization

I have multiple user and each user should have the option to upload some documents in his account.

I used this function in order to create a folder for each user at the registration process.

```
function create_user_dir($user_id) {
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $user_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/user_dirs/' . $user_info->user_login;

    wp_mkdir_p($user_dir);
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_user_dir');
```

Now I need to make the upload field, do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "do you have any idea"? There's still many open questions which you have to address. Where should the upload field be? Are there more restrictions? For the uploading itself you can probably use [`wp_handle_upload()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_upload/).

Comment: Each user should have something like a personal space (page) where he can upload different kind of documents (an admin should see in dashboard all the documents uploaded by the user).